# Unable to pass data from custom pre-handler middleware to _app.js

Tags: express, cookies, next.js

I'm trying to write a middleware that runs before the *NextJS* handler and checks if the session cookie received is valid/untampered. This is how I've wired it in my `server.js` file:

```
server.use('*', preLoadMiddleware);
server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));
```

The middleware itself attempts to set a local variable flagging authentication state:

```
import getSessIDFromCookies from '../utils/get-sessid-from-cookies';
import redis from 'redis';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const preLoadMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const client = redis.createClient(
    process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  );
  const cookieKeys = Object.keys(req.cookies);
  const sessCookie = getSessIDFromCookies(req);
  client.get(`sess:${sessCookie}`, (err, reply) => {
    if(reply) {
      console.log('SESSION VALID', reply);
      res.locals.authenticated = true;
    }
    else {
      console.log('SESSION NOT VALID');
      res.locals.authenticated = false;
    }
  });
  next();
};

module.exports = preLoadMiddleware;
```

Then in `_app.js`, I attempt to read this variable for further decisionmaking:

```
if (ctx.isServer) {
  if(ctx.res) {
    if(ctx.res.locals) {
      console.log('AUTHENTICATED', ctx.res.locals.authenticated);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is, `ctx.res.locals.authenticated` is always returning `undefined` in `_app.js`! What's going on?

I considered another alternative, setting a cookie in my middleware:

```
res.cookie('AUTHENTICATED', 'false')
```

But then it throws an error saying:

> Can't set headers after they are sent

Please help! How am I supposed to let `_app.js` know about my middleware's findings on session cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next() is called right away in the middleware. You may want to call that inside the callback. (client.get second arg) . Currently it is not waiting for the callback to be finished.

Comment: Tried that already, problem persists. I set `req.isauth = 1;` in the middleware, and it shows up as `ISAUTH undefined` when I try to `console.log('ISAUTH', ctx.req.isauth);` in `_app.jsx`.

Comment: Oh! Just noticed you are calling next() right away in the middleware. You may want to call that inside the callback. (client.get second arg) . Currently it is not waiting for the callback to be finished.

Comment: So THIS was the problem. I was calling `next()` outside the callback function which was making it trigger before the variable could be set. I moved it inside the callback and now it works as expected. But, I still got it to work using `res.locals` and not `req`. If you could update your answer with this comment of yours about `next()`, I could accept and close.